# Mongoose $pull method not working in my node.js application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a MERN stack application and I am learning while building a little bit of a complex blog application. So far, everything has gone well.
Here is what I want to do. An admin has the permission to delete single users, or all users or selected users.
I am writing the logic for selected users. So, from the frontend, the admin selects the users he would like to delete. The backend receives the ids of the selected users that came from the frontend. It is an array. So, the admin could select 10 users, etc.

I have a Post model where users' posts are stored. This post model has an object value called `postLikes` which is an array of `ids` of the users who liked that particular post.
Now, when the admin wants to delete some users, I also want everything about those users deleted including the likes. For example, if user A and user B were selected by the admin for deletion, and User A has already liked a post called Post B. But user B liked another post called Post F, their `ids` will be stored in the respective Post model, inside `postLikes`array values. I want to also remove their `ids` from any post they already liked before deleting them.

The selected `ids` came in as array. I searched for all Post models and filtered it to return posts with Likes. Here is the code:

```
 const posts = await Post.find();

 const filteredPost = posts.filter((singleFilter) => singleFilter.postLikes.length !== 0);
 const {selectedIds} = req.body;// contains array of selected posts coming from frontend

 for(i = 0; i < filteredPost.length; i++){
        for(h = 0; h < selectedIds.length; h++){
            if(filteredPost[i].postLikes == selectedIds[h]){
                
               const updatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(filteredPost[i]._id, { $pull: {postLikes: selectedIds[h] } })
              console.log(updatedPost)
            }
          
        }

    }
```

This code just runs without actually deleting the selected users' ids from their respective Post model `postLikes` array. I have also tried mongoose updateMany, didnt work.

Kindly help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```js
const posts = await Post.find();

const filteredPost = posts.filter((singleFilter) => singleFilter.postLikes.length !== 0);
const {selectedIds} = req.body;// contains array of selected posts coming from frontend


filteredPost.foreach(async post=>{
    /*
lets say your "postLikes" array looks like this: 
[{_id:"0",liked_by_user_with_id:"123"},
{_id:"1",liked_by_user_with_id:"456"},
{_id:"2",liked_by_user_with_id:"789"}]
   */ 

  
    post.postLikes.filter(like=>!selectedIds.includes(like.liked_by_user_with_id))
    await post.save();


});
```

Comment: This didnt work, Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the MongoDB server do all the work with something like this.  I suppose my array of ObjectIds used below would be replaced by `req.body` in your case, and you would use `updateMany` and not need `{"multi": true}`.

```js
db.Post.update({
  "postLikes": {
    "$in": [
      ObjectId("6309548f820a879df1436862"),
      ObjectId("6309548f820a879df1436867")
    ]
  }
},
{
  "$pullAll": {
    "postLikes": [
      ObjectId("6309548f820a879df1436862"),
      ObjectId("6309548f820a879df1436867")
    ]
  }
},
{"multi": true}
)
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bogmdmDAmqx).

I'm not a "Mongooser", but perhaps it would look like:

```js
const res = await Post.updateMany({"postLikes": {"$in": req.body }}, {"$pullAll": {"postLikes": req.body}});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but this didnt work.

Comment: @ThatkingzThatkingz Would you elaborate? mongoplayground.net doesn't lie - the `update` ran on a real MongoDB server and worked.

Comment: Thanks once again. Is this not the version of the code I am to use in my node.js? const res = await Post.updateMany({"postLikes": {"$in": req.body }}, {"$pullAll": {"postLikes": req.body}}); I replaced the req.body with my used case. I am using mongoose to query MongoDB

Comment: Only you can know what the parameters should be.  We don't know what `req.body` is.  You could also elaborate on what you mean by "didn't work".  What didn't work?  ... node error? ... MongoDB error?  ... no collection update? ... etc.?  After trying the line of code, what was the return result `res`?

Comment: Yes. I properly used my req.body in my own case. Here is my own code:  const res = await Post.updateMany({_id: {$in: newPost }}, {$pullAll: {postLikes: selectedIds}});

Comment: This is the error that I got when I console.log(res): {
  n: 4,
  electionId: 7fffffff00000000000000ab,
  opTime: {
    ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 16, high_: 1661594897 },
    t: 171
  },
  nModified: 4,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 16, high_: 1661594897 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 16, high_: 1661594897 }
}. When I checked mongodb, update was not carried out.

Comment: @ThatkingzThatkingz  ... and it updated the collection like you want?  `res.nModified` shows `4`.  I don't know what `newPost` or `selectedIds` but they should be arrays (see the MongoDB docs for `"$in"` and `"$pullAll"`).

Comment: It actually did not update the database. Like, the ids were not removed. The newPost is an array of ids of selected users' posts. That is to find the posts to be updated. The selectedIds is an array of users' ids. These ids need to be removed from the postLikes array of each post that contains them.

Comment: Why are `newPost` and `selectedIds` different?  Are you doing something other than what you described as your goal in the question?

Comment: It is same thing that I described. The newPost is same thing as filteredPosts._id. I simply made the posts ids that I wish to update an array. The selectedIds is simply the ids the admin selected from the frontend. To update the Post model, one can filter using _id parameter, postLikes, username, etc. I simply used _id.

Comment: So your code is working now?

Comment: Not working. Updates not reflecting on database.

Comment: `nModified: 4` contradicts that.

Comment: I am also shocked. I checked my database and the ids are still there. I can't be lying with that.